# transferring function data to observable array in knockout

Tags: filter, knockout.js

I have data to filter. this data will then be put into the foreach loop.
how can I get this data with a function, for example? here is the view:

```
enter code here<ul>
<!-- ko foreach: {data: Menus} -->
<!-- ko if: TitleId === 0 && Sub === true -->
<li>
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i><br><span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    <ul>
        <!-- ko foreach: {data: $parent.childMenus} -->
        <li>
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: $data.Url}">
                <span data-bind="text: $data.Name"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
</li>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: TitleId === 0 && Sub === false -->
<li>
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</li>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

and here is the view model:

```
self.Menu = ko.observable();
self.Menus = ko.observableArray();
self.childMenus = ko.observableArray();
self.currentFilter = ko.observable();
// Initialize the view-model
sendRequest(menuGetMenusUrl, "GET", null, function (data) {
    self.Menus.removeAll();
    self.Menus.push.apply(self.Menus, data);
});

self.childMenus = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Menus(), function (menu) {
        return menu.TitleId === self.currentFilter();
    });
});

self.filter = function (titleid) {
    self.currentFilter(titleid);
};
```

Comment: sorry 
i should have said hello first thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native javascript's `filter` method on array objects like so:

```
self.childMenus(self.Menus().filter((i) => i.someField == myDataToFilter ));
```

Filter will return an array with items matching the condition you put in, if nothing is found an empty array will be returned.

So all you have to do is `filter` on the underlying array, and assing the result to the childMenus array.

Comment: Make sure to check there is an array, even an empty one, on `Menus`, etc etc, but you should get the concept for your problem and adapt accordingly

Comment: thanks for your answer. In the loop, this filter array cannot work dynamically. I want the submenus to be spilled under each menu item in the loop.

Comment: Ok, but for us to help you on that you have to give the model definitions so that we can write something properly. All i gave you is the starting point, you can use it to put all child menus in the parent menu, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Ok MKougiouris. i edited my question. parent.childMenus must be refreshed dynamically. so, each sub menu sequence will change according to the individual parent id value. thank you very much.